# What's the lightest weight portable keyboard / USB-C monitor on the market?

Tags: monitors, keyboards, usb-c, portable

I need something slim and lightweight for travel. I have a surface + fintie Bluetooth keyboard now that has served me well for years

But I want to go smaller. I don't think foldable phones are quite there yet. However, my phone can definitely replace my surface if I can find a lightweight enough monitor to justify it

I never actually use my laptop for anything except a text editor. So it's a waste of power and space.

I just need something that's big enough (vertically) to see a decent amount of code and a keyboard that is either slim or fits in my pocket.

I'd take either.

The lightest weight portable monitor I've found is a 12.5" Faytech USB-C which looks to be the winner. Honestly, I could probably get by with 8-10".

The keyboard I'm stumped on. I've looked at Moko and similar folding keyboard designs.

These leave out the pointing device (trackpad) which is fixable with a sub-100g mouse like the ProPoint that is miniscule.

However, this seems quite convoluted.

Comment: Two notes, I am not sure your question is even answerable as is. 1) There are 7-8" laptops , these days they are more commonly gaming consoles but there are laptops too, GPD and One Notebook makes them. 2) The smallest keyboards with some sort of TrackPoint is the Motorola Wireless Keyboard with Device Stand and the Samsung AA-SK0TKBD (for the Q1 UMPC). Both are about 24cm wide.